# Where to run javascript to solve tsp with GA

Tags: javascript, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I have programmed a tsp-solver with genetic algorithm, but i have to solve it for 11000 cities. In the browser it gets very slow and hangs. 
How can I run javascript the fastest way?

Maybe with node.js in the Mac terminal or with node.js on an amazon EC2 server or with firebase cloud functions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, running the engine standalone (in node.js) might give you more control  about the environment, and not affect your surfing. (Of course it still will be slow and eat your CPU). On which machine - your local mac, a cloud instance, or something else - to run the program only you can decide.

Comment: Some more thought: How often do you need to solve the problem (run the program)? How does input and output work (or what would be most convenient for you)?

Comment: Usage of JavaScript for such problem can be only for demonstration. If you need to solve this problem for some real application, select better language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to solve with js. You need to run your code near by CPU. I prefer C,C++ with correct parameters. Then you can build engine as service. If speed not your first criteria, you can use server side technologies look like nodejs, php, .net. You need caching mechanism for saving solutions. If you plan to use AWS, you can check AWS lambda services. I prefer use own server without virtual instance. Virtual instance has low memory access speed. You need to make a lot of test for determining your correct platform.